# Submitting a form creates an entry but does not register text

Tags: html, css, forms, google-docs

I've embedded a Google Form into my website.

When I click the submit button on my website, the form registers that something has been inputted and the Google Form Doc creates an entry. However, the text that I inputted on my website does not show up (in other words, the submit button is sending blank data).

Here's my code:

```
<div id="container">

  <script type="text/javascript">var submitted=false;</script>

  <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted) {window.location='index.html';}"></iframe>

  <form action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dENQRHl0Um5rYms1RExxWkJta1ZTZEE6MQ&ifq" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
    <div id="box">
      <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_1"></label>
      <input type="text" name="entry.1.single" value="" class="ss-q-short input_box" id="entry_1">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_box btn">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Can anyone see what the problem might be? Let me know if anything needs clarification. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As I see from a google doc form on this page https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dENQRHl0Um5rYms1RExxWkJta1ZTZEE6MQ&ifq  you are using wrong name for that text input

So correct form code would look like this I think:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dENQRHl0Um5rYms1RExxWkJta1ZTZEE6MQ&ifq" method="post" target="hidden_iframe" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
    <div id="box">
      <label class="ss-q-help" for="entry_0"></label>
      <input type="text" name="entry.0.single" value="" class="ss-q-short input_box" id="entry_0">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_box btn">
    </div>
</form>
```